# Loop through each Excel file in a folder, to the same sheet to copy the same range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through each Excel file in a folder, to the same sheet to copy the same range to another Excel file.

I had a code but it was not displaying the copy paste correctly (e.g. was showing 1,2479 as 12.479). I looked for a new code and found and enhanced one.

However, for just nine files, this code runs for over three minutes. The folder would have around 50 files, so I am a bit worried that excel won't be able to handle it.

I read a lot about not using `.Select`, but I believe I am not doing that.

I am using Excel 2010

Original Code

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String

'Setting the right folder where the cartographies are
Filepath = "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive - xxx\Testexcel\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0
'Application.DecimalSeparator = ","
'Application.ThousandsSeparator = "."
'Application.UseSystemSeparators = False

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    'If MyFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then
    'Exit Sub
    'End If
    
    'Open all the workbook
    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
    'Activate the right worksheet in the cartography file
    Worksheets("xxxxxx").Activate
    'Highlight the range of cells we want to copy
    Range("E2:H2").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
    'Add the copied cells to our sheet in the master file
    Worksheets("xxxxxx").Activate
    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
    
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

'Application.UseSystemSeparators = True

End Sub
```

Current code

```
Sub Merge2MultiSheets()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xSelItem As Variant
Dim FileDlg As FileDialog
Dim FileName, Standalone, Range2copy As String
Dim Cartography As Workbook
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Optimize Code
Call OptimizeCode_Begin
'Give the name of the sheet of cartography where data should be gathered
Standalone = "xxxxxxxx"
'Say the range of the data to be copied from the sheet
Range2copy = "E2:H2"

Set Workbook = ThisWorkbook
Set TargetSheet = Workbook.Sheets("Consolidated Cartography")

'Ask in pop-up where the folder is located with the excel files to update
Set FileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FileDlg
    If .Show = -1 Then
        xSelItem = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        FileName = Dir(xSelItem & "\*.xls*", vbNormal)
        If FileName = "" Then Exit Sub
        Do Until FileName = ""
        'Open the first file in the folder
            Set Cartography = Workbooks.Open(xSelItem & "\" & FileName)
            'Open the right active sheet with data to be copied and put range into xRg
            Set xRg = Cartography.Worksheets(Standalone).Range(Range2copy)
            'Copy  xRg to the TargetSheet at location starting at A250, go up to last row with data then one down
            xRg.Copy TargetSheet.Range("A250").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            FileName = Dir()
            Cartography.Close
        Loop
    End If
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Optimize Code
Call OptimizeCode_End
End Sub
```

I found this on the internet. It does try to make code faster by disabling some events and triggers.

```
Sub OptimizeCode_Begin()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

EventState = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False

CalcState = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

End Sub

Sub OptimizeCode_End()

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
Application.Calculation = CalcState
Application.EnableEvents = EventState
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that declaring `Dim FileName, Standalone, Range2copy As String` will only declare `Range2copy As String` but all the others as `Variant` you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim FileName As String, Standalone As String, Range2copy As String`.

Comment: Oh really? I did not know that. My, bad thanks for the information! I am currently also looking to take online classes to improve my understanding and knowledge of VBA.

Comment: Keep in mind that using this kind of speed improvements carries some risk as well.  If you aren't using good error handling, they can leave Excel in a bad state.   Make sure that you are using error handling to make sure that in the event of a failure in your code, these changes get re-set back to their original values.

Comment: Make sure that if you do use the `OptimizeCode_Begin`, that you set up `Public` variables to hold the `PageBreakState`, `CalcState` and `EventState` or you will end up with some issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of speed improvement can be gained by counting the target rows instead of finding them in every loop. So in the initialisation phase (out of loop):

```
Dim iTrgRow As Long
iTrgRow = TargetSheet.Range("A250").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

Then in the loop:

```
Cartography.Worksheets(Standalone).Range(Range2copy).Copy Destination:=TargetSheet.Cells(iTrgRow, 1)
iTrgRow = iTrgRow + 1
```

This will paste the copy buffer to column A, iTrgRow. It's OK as long as you copy one row of data.

For OptimizeCode collection: I agree with the comments above. Yet, you can turn off DisplayPageBreaks, Calculation, EnableEvents, ScreenUpdating, but I would leave DisplayAlerts on.

Comment: Thank you! It is improving the time by around 40 seconds! I did not think of putting the target row outside of the loop. Smart move.

However, somehow it keeps posting the first data row on the first row of the excel sheet even though it says EndxlUP and offset by 1 at the start. Not sure what is triggering it. The fact that there is only text in the first row? It would need to be coppied starting from the second row.

Comment: My fault. Edited the answer. I left out `.Row` at the end. Anyway, it is a good lesson to learn that `.End(xlUp).Row` returns 1 regardless of whether the cell in 1st row is empty or not.

Comment: Oh I understand! Thanks :)